# Force Ember component to re-render from within its route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

We develop an Ember based framework for internal use of various groups within our organization. Along with this, we maintain a demo page, which displays all the components we've developed along with documentation on how to use the components. I need to modify one of the component demo pages, to allow the user to custom build the component. For example, the component has two properties showCheckboxes and showRadioButtons. By default, showCheckboxes  is true, and the component, of course, displays checkboxes. I want to add a select so the user can choose between radio buttons and checkboxes. Everything is wired up correctly and the routes action gets called, but, if I select radioButtons, the component does not refresh and display readio buttons. I've set breakpoints and I see that the route is not called, so the new properties are not read. How can I force Ember to rebuild the component from scratch? I've tried this.refresh() in the route, I've tried setting the model to the new model with the changes, but the component does not redraw with the new properties. I've also tried transitionTo. But if I don't pass a model, nothing happens. But if I pass in the new route, I get this error:

**Error: More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route**

I hope this was clear enough for someone to provide some guidance.
Thanks

Comment: The component should be live-bound so this should work. Your problem is probably a `transitionTo()` or a `{{link}}` that is not correct. Could you provide a not working ember-twiddle?

Comment: I'll put something together. Its internal code and I can't really post it, but I'll put together a pared down version later today. Thanks